Tag for questions about dealing with switch/case constructs
So, I was looking at this question about jump tables, hoping to navigate from there to some other questions relating to switch/case constructs, but unfortunately the question turned out not to have a tag relating to that.
I would just suggest an edit to add such a tag to the question, but:

I couldn't find an existing tag for that
I'm not sure what the tag should be called

Since the code I'm looking at is using a series of dec/sub instructions interspersed with jz, I'm especially hoping for a tag that isn't specific to jump-table based implementation techniques, but would apply to any way of implementing switch/case constructs: jump tables, series' or trees of comparisons, combinations thereof, or any other method that may exist.
Does this seem like a good idea, and if so what should the tag be called?

This doesn't seem to be a common topic so I'm not sure how useful such tag would be. But if you do want to add one, I'd go with something obvious like 'switch'.
As a possible alternative, I would suggest a more generic tag covering low-level details of compiled programs. Maybe something like 'compiler-assembly' or 'implementation-detail(s)'?
Related: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13632/what-are-good-rules-for-naming-tags
